# Unable to view the image in page

Tags: html

Following is a piece of xsl code

```
<tr>
  <td class="colHeader1">Last Name
  </td>
  <td class="cellstyle1">
     <input type="text" name="srchLname" style="width:100%" tabindex="1"/>
  </td>
  <td class="colHeader1">Primary Telephone
  </td>
  <td class="cellstyle1">
     <input type="text"  name="srchPhone"  style="width:100%"></input>
  </td>
  <td rowspan="2" align="right">
    <img src="images/search.gif" style="cursor:hand" onclick="doCustSrch()"></img>
    <img src="images/clear.gif" style="cursor:hand" onclick="clearCustSrch()"></img>
  </td>
</tr>
```

On using this code the images doesnt showup in the page(`search.gif`,`clear.gif`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is not an **ASP** issue but rather a **physical position** one.

Let's imagine that you have this tree of contents:

```
|
|-- _Assets
|     |-- Css
|          |-- styles.css
|     |-- Scripts
|          |-- jquery.min.js
|     |-- Images
|          |-- search.gif
|          |-- clear.gif
|-- Admin
|     |-- default.asp
|-- Account
|     |-- default.asp
|-- ...
|
```

if you want to point to the `search.gif` image from `Admin/default.asp` your image localization will be:

1. You are in the `Admin` folder, so let's go back one folder, positioning in the `root`

   `../`
2. Let's find the entire path from the root now

   `_Assets/Images/Search.gif`
3. Join both paths

   `<img src="../_Assets/Images/Search.gif" alt="" />`

You you are using a CSS styling under `styles.css` your start position is the folder that holds the `styles.css` file and never the page where it's been called.

So, in your example, you should see if you have something like this:

```
|-- mypage.asp
|-- images
|     |-- search.gif
|     |-- clear.gif
```

I hope this helps you clear any wondering in pointing the files to and from where.

---

Just for your information, and I don't know if the old ASP uses the `~` char, but in ASP.NET we tend to use:

```
`<img src="~/_Assets/Images/Search.gif" alt="" />`
```

where the `~` wildcard char means "Root of website", so, no matter where we are, in a file under `n` child folders or in the root, the path is always the full path with the `~` char on the start.